# Xcode Table Cell Image Overlap

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I'm learning Objective C & working on an Instagram clone for a class assignment. Currently I have a problem with auto layout. Specifically, images & comments are overlapping on each other:

[image: Image Overlap]

I believe the problem is in the auto layout:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        self.mediaImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        self.usernameAndCaptionLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        self.usernameAndCaptionLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        self.commentLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        self.commentLabel.numberOfLines = 0;

        for (UIView *view in @[self.mediaImageView, self.usernameAndCaptionLabel, self.commentLabel]) {
            [self.contentView addSubview:view];
            view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        }
        NSDictionary *viewDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_mediaImageView, _usernameAndCaptionLabel, _commentLabel);

        [self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[_mediaImageView]|" options:kNilOptions metrics:nil views:viewDictionary]];
        [self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[_usernameAndCaptionLabel]|" options:kNilOptions metrics:nil views:viewDictionary]];
        [self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[_commentLabel]|" options:kNilOptions metrics:nil views:viewDictionary]];

        [self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[_mediaImageView][_usernameAndCaptionLabel][_commentLabel]"
                                                                                 options:kNilOptions
                                                                                 metrics:nil
                                                                                   views:viewDictionary]];
        self.imageHeightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_mediaImageView
                                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                     toItem:nil
                                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                                 multiplier:1
                                                                   constant:100];


        self.usernameAndCaptionLabelHeightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_usernameAndCaptionLabel
                                                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                                                    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                                       toItem:nil
                                                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                                                   multiplier:1
                                                                                     constant:100];

        self.commentLabelHeightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_commentLabel
                                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                                         relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                            toItem:nil
                                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                                        multiplier:1
                                                                          constant:100];

        [self.contentView addConstraints:@[self.imageHeightConstraint, self.usernameAndCaptionLabelHeightConstraint, self.commentLabelHeightConstraint]];    }
    return self;
}
```

I've gone through the class tutorial several time and have researched iOS SDK Table Cell Overlapping but have not been able to find a suitable answer.

Here is the entire code:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "UITableViewCell+BLCMediaTableViewCell.h"
#import "NSObject+BLCMedia.h"
#import "NSObject+BLCComment.h"
#import "NSObject+BLCUser.h"


//@implementation UITableViewCell (BLCMediaTableViewCell)

@interface BLCMediaTableViewCell() {
    BLCMedia* _mediaItem;
}


@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *mediaImageView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *usernameAndCaptionLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *commentLabel;

// Assignment: Added auto layout
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSLayoutConstraint *imageHeightConstraint;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSLayoutConstraint *usernameAndCaptionLabelHeightConstraint;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSLayoutConstraint *commentLabelHeightConstraint;

@end

static UIFont *lightFont;
static UIFont *boldFont;
static UIColor *usernameLabelGray;
static UIColor *commentLabelGray;
static UIColor *linkColor;
static NSParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle;

@implementation BLCMediaTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

- (void) layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    // Before layout, calculate the intrinsic size of the labels (the size they "want" to be), and add 20 to the height for some vertical padding.

    self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(self.imageView.frame.origin.x, self.imageView.frame.origin.y, 100, 100);

    CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds), CGFLOAT_MAX);
    CGSize usernameLabelSize = [self.usernameAndCaptionLabel sizeThatFits:maxSize];
    CGSize commentLabelSize = [self.commentLabel sizeThatFits:maxSize];

    self.usernameAndCaptionLabelHeightConstraint.constant = usernameLabelSize.height + 20;
    self.commentLabelHeightConstraint.constant = commentLabelSize.height + 20;

    // Hide the line between cells
    self.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds));
}


+ (void)load {
    lightFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Thin" size:11];
    boldFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:11];
    usernameLabelGray = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.933 green:0.933 blue:0.933 alpha:1]; /*#eeeeee*/
    commentLabelGray = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.898 green:0.898 blue:0.898 alpha:1]; /*#e5e5e5*/
    linkColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.345 green:0.314 blue:0.427 alpha:1]; /*#58506d*/

    NSMutableParagraphStyle *mutableParagraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
    mutableParagraphStyle.headIndent = 20.0;
    mutableParagraphStyle.firstLineHeadIndent = 20.0;
    mutableParagraphStyle.tailIndent = -20.0;
    mutableParagraphStyle.paragraphSpacingBefore = 5;

    paragraphStyle = mutableParagraphStyle;

}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        self.mediaImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        self.usernameAndCaptionLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        self.usernameAndCaptionLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        self.commentLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        self.commentLabel.numberOfLines = 0;


        for (UIView *view in @[self.mediaImageView, self.usernameAndCaptionLabel, self.commentLabel]) {
            [self.contentView addSubview:view];
            view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        }
        NSDictionary *viewDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_mediaImageView, _usernameAndCaptionLabel, _commentLabel);

        [self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[_mediaImageView]|" options:kNilOptions metrics:nil views:viewDictionary]];
        [self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[_usernameAndCaptionLabel]|" options:kNilOptions metrics:nil views:viewDictionary]];
        [self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[_commentLabel]|" options:kNilOptions metrics:nil views:viewDictionary]];

        [self.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[_mediaImageView][_usernameAndCaptionLabel][_commentLabel]"
                                                                                 options:kNilOptions
                                                                                 metrics:nil
                                                                                   views:viewDictionary]];
        self.imageHeightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_mediaImageView
                                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                     toItem:nil
                                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                                 multiplier:1
                                                                   constant:100];


        self.usernameAndCaptionLabelHeightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_usernameAndCaptionLabel
                                                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                                                    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                                       toItem:nil
                                                                                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                                                   multiplier:1
                                                                                     constant:100];

        self.commentLabelHeightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_commentLabel
                                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                                         relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                            toItem:nil
                                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                                        multiplier:1
                                                                          constant:100];

        [self.contentView addConstraints:@[self.imageHeightConstraint, self.usernameAndCaptionLabelHeightConstraint, self.commentLabelHeightConstraint]];    }
    return self;
}




- (NSAttributedString *) usernameAndCaptionString {
    CGFloat usernameFontSize = 15;

    // Make a string that says "username caption text"
    NSString *baseString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", self.mediaItem.user.userName, self.mediaItem.caption];

    // Make an attributed string, with the "username" bold
    NSMutableAttributedString *mutableUsernameAndCaptionString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:baseString attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [lightFont fontWithSize:usernameFontSize], NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : paragraphStyle}];

    NSRange usernameRange = [baseString rangeOfString:self.mediaItem.user.userName];
    [mutableUsernameAndCaptionString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[boldFont fontWithSize:usernameFontSize] range:usernameRange];
    [mutableUsernameAndCaptionString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:linkColor range:usernameRange];

    return mutableUsernameAndCaptionString;
}


- (void) setMediaItem:(BLCMedia *)mediaItem {
    _mediaItem = mediaItem;
    self.mediaImageView.image = _mediaItem.image;
    self.usernameAndCaptionLabel.attributedText = [self usernameAndCaptionString];
    self.commentLabel.attributedText = [self commentString];

    self.imageHeightConstraint.constant = self.mediaItem.image.size.height / self.mediaItem.image.size.width * CGRectGetWidth(self.contentView.bounds);
}

//Added
- (CGSize) sizeOfString:(NSAttributedString *)string {
        CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.contentView.bounds) - 40, 0.0);
        CGRect sizeRect = [string boundingRectWithSize:maxSize options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin context:nil];
        sizeRect.size.height += 20;
        sizeRect = CGRectIntegral(sizeRect);
        return sizeRect.size;
    }



- (NSAttributedString *) commentString {
    NSMutableAttributedString *commentString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] init];

    for (BLCComment *comment in self.mediaItem.comments) {
        // Make a string that says "username comment text" followed by a line break
        NSString *baseString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@\n", comment.from.userName, comment.text];

        // Make an attributed string, with the "username" bold

        NSMutableAttributedString *oneCommentString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:baseString attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : lightFont, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : paragraphStyle}];

        NSRange usernameRange = [baseString rangeOfString:comment.from.userName];
        [oneCommentString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:boldFont range:usernameRange];
        [oneCommentString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:linkColor range:usernameRange];

        [commentString appendAttributedString:oneCommentString];
    }

    return commentString;
}

+ (CGFloat) heightForMediaItem:(BLCMedia *)mediaItem width:(CGFloat)width {
    // Make a cell
    BLCMediaTableViewCell *layoutCell = [[BLCMediaTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"layoutCell"];
    [layoutCell setNeedsLayout];
    [layoutCell layoutIfNeeded];

    // Get the actual height required for the cell
    return CGRectGetMaxY(layoutCell.commentLabel.frame);
}

@end
```

Comment: So how should it look? Image and text below, then next image and text etc ? And if you're using constraints, why are you also setting frames?

Comment: How is the table VC working out the height? - are you calling heightForMediaItem in -heightForRowAtIndexPath:? Or are you using the iOS 8 only estimatedHeight method. Also, -heightForMediaItem: width: looks odd - you are passing a BLCMedia params that is not used. It will instantiate a new cell every time you calculate a height -it's more efficient to use a single prototype cell stored as an ivar on the table view controller. If you are iOS 8 only, you shouldn't even need that.

Comment: @RichTolley, I did realize that I missed some code `//This was the missing code//
    layoutCell.mediaItem = mediaItem;
    layoutCell.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, CGRectGetHeight(layoutCell.frame));
    // ^ ^ ^ Missing Code ^ ^ ^` which fixed most of the problem (updated image in Dropbox) but there is still a bit of overlap. I didn't know about the new iOS8 method so I will try to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out what I was doing wrong. My layoutSubViews were incorrect. I've included a screenshot of the bad version & the corrected version in my public [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/e8mwhunh16v9hmx/AACNj34KXlL9C6jS-eOGSsx3a?dl=0). I hope this can help someone else later down the road.

[image]

The original code was:

```
    - (void) layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    // Before layout, calculate the intrinsic size of the labels (the size they "want" to be), and add 20 to the height for some vertical padding.

    self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(self.imageView.frame.origin.x, self.imageView.frame.origin.y, 100, 100);

    CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds), CGFLOAT_MAX);
    CGSize usernameLabelSize = [self.usernameAndCaptionLabel sizeThatFits:maxSize];
    CGSize commentLabelSize = [self.commentLabel sizeThatFits:maxSize];

    self.usernameAndCaptionLabelHeightConstraint.constant = usernameLabelSize.height + 20;
    self.commentLabelHeightConstraint.constant = commentLabelSize.height + 20;

    // Hide the line between cells
    self.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds));
}
```

It should have read:

```
    - (void) layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    if (self.mediaItem == nil){
        return;
    }

    // Before layout, calculate the intrinsic size of the labels (the size they "want" to be), and add 20 to the height for some vertical padding.
    CGSize maxSize = CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds), CGFLOAT_MAX);
    CGSize usernameLabelSize = [self.usernameAndCaptionLabel sizeThatFits:maxSize];
    CGSize commentLabelSize = [self.commentLabel sizeThatFits:maxSize];

    self.usernameAndCaptionLabelHeightConstraint.constant = usernameLabelSize.height + 20;
    self.commentLabelHeightConstraint.constant = commentLabelSize.height + 20;

    if (_mediaItem.image)
    {
        self.imageHeightConstraint.constant = self.mediaItem.image.size.height / self.mediaItem.image.size.width * CGRectGetWidth(self.contentView.bounds);
    }
    else
    {
        self.imageHeightConstraint.constant = 100;
    }

    //Hide the line between cells
    self.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds));
}
```